# Wrapping/warping a CALayer/UIView (or OpenGL) in 3D (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, core-animation, transform, calayer

I've got a UIView (and thus a CALayer) which I'm trying to warp or bend slightly in 3D space. That is, imagine my UIView is a flat label which I want to partially wrap around a beer bottle (not 360 degrees around, just on one "side").

I figured this would be possible by applying a transform to the view's layer, but as far as I can tell, this transform is limited to rotation, scale and translation of the layer uniformly. I could be wrong here, as my linear algebra is foggy at this point, to say the least.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need OpenGL for this. (I don't know how.)

Comment: Kenny's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351586/iphone-image-stretching-skew shows how to do more complex distortions of a 2-D layer, but I don't believe curvature is possible using only transforms like that.

Comment: @Brad Larson: Right, I can do skews like that no problem. It's curvature I'm after. I know nothing of OpenGL but if someone does that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Apple's sample code [PVRTextureLoader](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PVRTextureLoader/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008121)
This is an OpenGL project that demonstrates how to display a texture (your label) on a surface (on a cylinder in your case).

Jeff LaMarche has posted a nice [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html) to get started with Open GL.

Comment: How is this answer relevant? It's the right direction, but it doesn't mention anything about "bending" a layer.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do with Core Animation is to do a piecewise-linear approximation.

For instance, you might divide your "cylinder" into eight segments, and arrange them like so:

```
  _
 / \
|   |
```

You could give them all the same image but change the translation so that they line up at the edges. Then give each a transform (either a simple horizontal compression or a sort of "keystone" if you are going for a perspective look).

In reality you'd probably want to use more than eight segments. Note that they would be concentrated near the edges of your view.

[This CSS animation](http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css-coke-can/) might give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few "distort" examples on this page: http://www.sgi.com/products/software/opengl/examples/more_samples/

I (honestly) am not sure how to do it, but I have had this page Bookmarked for quite some time to try to Warp/Morph a UIView with a mesh/grid.

Best of luck.

^.^