# How to shear images in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to find out how to shear images in IOS 4.0. I have an image. The output should look like the following image...

[image]

I have seen the Affine transform [method specified here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/cgaffinetransform-11-little-more.html). But couldnt solve my problem. It would be of great help of i can find any solution or tutorials to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you: [iPhone image stretching (skew)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351586/iphone-image-stretching-skew/2352402#2352402)

Comment: Thanks Luke. This seems to be a bit complicated. Can anyone please post some working sample or a tutorial of it... Plzzzz....