# skewing a UIImageView using CGAffineTransform

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to skew a rectangle so the two vertical sides are slanted but parallel and the top and bottom are horizontal.

I am trying to use CGAffineTransform and have found this code but I am not figuring out what to put in the various parts.

```
imageView.layer.somethingMagic.imageRightTop = (CGPoint){ 230, 30 };
                imageView.layer.somethingMagic.imageRightBottom = (CGPoint){ 300, 150 };

#define CGAffineTransformDistort(t, x, y) (CGAffineTransformConcat(t, CGAffineTransformMake(1, y, x, 1, 0, 0)))
#define CGAffineTransformMakeDistort(x, y) (CGAffineTransformDistort(CGAffineTransformIdentity, x, y))
```

although this is said to be easy I don't know what to put in the different places.

I assume image view would be my image that I want to change however what goes into somethingMagic. and imageRightTop and imageRightBottom.

Also how do I define t.

If there is a more thorough explanation I would appreciate it since in most cases I found only this as the explanation of what to do to skew a rectangle.

Thanks

Comment: more excellent answers here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203738/iphone-skew-a-calayer

Comment: Hear is a good article by 'Eduardo Irías' for [Swift Transforms](https://medium.com/weeronline/swift-transforms-5981398b437d) on medium.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's assume you have a variable named `imageView` holding a reference to your `UIImageView`.
I wrote a little sample to demonstrate how you could get this behavior. What this code does is creating a new `CGAffineTransform` matrix. This matrix has the same values as the identity transform matrix with one exception: the value at location [2,1]. This value is controlled by the `c`-parameter of the `CGAffineTransformMake`-function and controls the shearing along the x-axis. You can change the amount of shearing by setting `shearValue`.

The code:

#### Objective-C

```c
CGFloat shearValue = 0.3f; // You can change this to anything you want
CGAffineTransform shearTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.f, 0.f, shearValue, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
[imageView setTransform:shearTransform];
```

#### Swift 5

```swift
let shearValue = CGFloat(0.3) // You can change this to anything you want
let shearTransform = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: shearValue, d: 1, tx: 0, ty: 0)
imageView.transform = shearTransform
```

And here's what the `shearTransform`-matrix looks like:

```
[1     0     0]  
[0.3   1     0]  
[0     0     1]
```

Comment: this is great. just what I needed.  However I had applied `self.imageViewreflex.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1);` to the uiimageView to turn it upside down,  but by applying this, your code, it's no longer upside down.  Do you know what happened and how to get the upside down back.

Comment: figured this out just changed fourth value to a negative.

Comment: @s1m0n, Which value provides a shear in the Y dimension?

Comment: @DuncanC, transpose s1m0n's matrix and you'll get a Y dimension shear