# Perform uneven stretch draw with Delphi

Tags: delphi, canvas

OK, this is something that is best explained with an image...

[image: uneven stretch draw of an image]

I am looking for a function similar to StretchBlt but where i can copy an image to a canvas defining the four corners of the destination, i.e. a Trapezoid/Quadrilateral stretch draw of an image onto a canvas.

I can think of a number of slow ways to do this, but I want to know if there is something of a similar speed to StretchBlt (e.g. no more than ten times slower).

Thanks

Comment: There is a very good description how to do this here [iphone-image-stretching-skew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351586/iphone-image-stretching-skew).

Comment: How about [PlgBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162804(VS.85).aspx)?

Comment: @LU RD: Yes, that is what i want to do, but i am hoping for a specific routine or windows API...

Comment: @Downvoterstepintothelight: Yes, PlgBlt would be fantastic, but unfortunately it only blts a parallelogram rather than a Trapezoid :-(

Answer (score 7):

There are very fast methods for this in the [Graphics32](http://www.graphics32.org) library.

Comment: Yes, G32 is very good, but alas I can't use any third party libraries.