# Get the current skew angle of an UIView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, cgaffinetransform, skew

How can I get the current angle of a skewed image?

The code I use to skew it is:

```
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, tan(angle*(M_PI/480)), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGFloat skew_c = [(NSNumber *)[view valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.c"] floatValue];
```

Keypath is guesstimated, but should work. [CGAffineTransformMake docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000946-CH1g-F16980).

EDIT:

Looks like CGAffineTransform is translated into 4x4 [`CATransform3D`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CATransform3D) matrix.

`transform` is property of `CALayer` `of CATransform3D` type.

That means you can acces `m11`..`m44` parameters with calls like:

```
CGFloat m11 = [(NSNumber *)[view valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.m11"] floatValue];
...
...
CGFloat m44 = [(NSNumber *)[view valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.m44"] floatValue];
```

You'd still need to do some calculations to get your skew factor. You can derive equation for your c_factor from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2352402/653513).

Comment: I don't understand how to do it yet =(

Comment: I'm also trying to figure it out. The problem is that the parameters you give to `CGAffineTransformMake` are translated to a different kind of matrix so you can't get them back by simply reading them. [3D projection - Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) is also helpfull but quite complex.

Comment: Here's a document that seems very promising:[Matrices, Quartz 2D, CGAffineTransform, CATransform3D](http://www.odysseyinc.com/downloads/EnterTheMatrix.pdf)

Comment: I've solved it creating a custom UIView and adding a skewAngle property to it.

Comment: Congratulations, simplest solution is usually the best one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[view valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CGFloat radians = atan2f([self myview].transform.b, [self myview].transform.a);
```

With this you can get a current angle of any `UIView`.

Keep Rocking... enjoy... :)

Comment: Thank you. Fattie