# UIImageView 3D distortion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, distortion

I've been looking stackoverflow and the internet for quite some time, but can't seem to find anything usable.

I'd like to achieve this:
[image: UIImage distortion]

Where it's important that I can change the four corner's origin.
Something like this:

```
imageView.layer.somethingMagic.imageRightTop = (CGPoint){ 230, 30 };
imageView.layer.somethingMagic.imageRightBottom = (CGPoint){ 300, 150 };
```

and it result into a deformed "3D" image.

I don't need actually working code, just some pointers where/what to look for.

Comment: See this similar question for a discussion of how to do distortions like this with a CATransform3D: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351586/iphone-image-stretching-skew

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CGAffineTransformConcat` / `CGAffineTransformDistort`. There is a tutorial here showing how to do it:

http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/ios-distort-transform

> ```
> #define CGAffineTransformDistort(t, x, y) (CGAffineTransformConcat(t, CGAffineTransformMake(1, y, x, 1, 0, 0)))
> #define CGAffineTransformMakeDistort(x, y) (CGAffineTransformDistort(CGAffineTransformIdentity, x, y))
> ```

Obviously don't use it in a `UIViewAnimation` as shown in the example on the above page.

Comment: That will only work for skewing, as described by KennyTM here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2352402/19679 . A 2-D affine transform will not be able to achieve the effect they want in the image above.